# Does the color of wool dictate the type of painting yielded from crafting?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to decorate my castle's gallery room with paintings of different types. Does the color of the wool affect the painting, or is it just random.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, paintings are created randomly when you place it on a surface, so the type of wool doesn't matter.

If you don't like the painting after placing it just break it, collect the painting item that drops, and place it again: Minecraft will again randomly choose a painting that fits the space. You can keep repeating this until you get a painting you like.